# How do I stub functions in python?

Tags: python, function, stub

It's my first few lessons in programming and i've encountered a question that i don't really understand how to proceed.

```
def defeat_balrog(protagonist):    
    def spawn_balrog():
        """Spawns and returns a stubborn balrog"""
        pass
    def balrog_attack(balrog, person):
        """Returns an attack move from the balrog's repertoire"""
        pass
    cave_balrog = spawn_balrog()
    is_balrog_defeated = False
   yell(protagonist, 'You cannot pass!')
    while not is_balrog_defeated:
        current_attack = balrog_attack(cave_balrog, protagonist)
        if current_attack != None:
            take_defensive_action(protagonist, current_attack)
        yell(protagonist, 'YOU SHALL NOT PASS!')
        take_offensive_action(protagonist, cave_balrog)
        is_balrog_defeated = True
    return True

def take_defensive_action(attacked_entity, attack_move):
    """
    attacked_entity anticipates attack_move and defends himself.
    """
    pass
#my stubs here#
defeat_balrog('gandalf')
```

I'm supposed to identify the remaining functions that have been wishfully used, but for which stubs have not been created, and fill in from the last line #my stubs here#. not sure how to get started or proceed on.

Comment: You haven't said what your problem is. What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: You already have stubs. Functions that pass and do nothing

Comment: If you didn't understand your assignment, why didn't you ask the instructor who gave it to you to explain what they meant? That's exactly what they're being paid to do.

Comment: As @KenWhite states, this question is not really programming related. It is more an issue that you did not understand what is asked in the assignment, and is thus better clarified with your instructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A stub is a function that exists but for which no meaningful business logic has been defined. For example:

```
def take_defensive_action(attacked_entity, attack_move):
    pass
```

Notice the pass statement here? It means that you've defined a valid function, but it does nothing.

---

Pasting your code into PyCharm, I see the following functions highlighted in "yellow" (that means those function names have an `Unresolved reference`):

- `yell(protagonist, 'YOU SHALL NOT PASS!')`
- `take_offensive_action(protagonist, cave_balrog)`

Clear on the meaning of what a stub is, you should be able to define these functions accordingly as they haven't been defined yet. Here's an example for `yell`:

```
def yell(protagonist, message):
    pass
```

I leave the second to you.